# Error while trying to create a dynamic visual force page

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce

I am trying to create a dynamic visual force page and am referring https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Dynamic_Visualforce_Components

I am getting the below error when trying to save the class:

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: core.apexpages.quickfix.QuickFixException:
>   Component c:apex does not exist

Below is my code:

```
public with sharing class CreateSurvey {
    public List<Component.Apex> components; 
    public Component.Apex.PageBlock CreateSurveyPage() {
        Component.Apex.PageBlock surveyBlock = new Component.Apex.PageBlock();

    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Delete the second line. Where you do need to represent a collection of these dynamic components, the appropriate type to use is [ApexPages.Component](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_dynamic_components.htm).

Comment: Keith C you should flesh your comment ^ out into an answer.

Comment: Ah.. Am not getting the error anymore. So does that mean that we cannot create a list of such components? I have not substituted with ApexPages.Component.